# Angular upload 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, upload

When try upload images with angular get error  405 (Method Not Allowed)

[Online example](http://infoprijedor.info/)

I'm change headers im my source but again error, any solution?

When change URL to https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload  work fine on my destination not working!

Answer (score 0):

Your destination needs to be Web API that handles POST.
Something like that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
public class FileUploadController : ApiController
{

    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var docfiles = new List<string>();
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/" + postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                docfiles.Add(filePath);
            }
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, docfiles);
        }
        else
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        return result;
    }


}
}
```

See step-by-step [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/uploading-a-file-in-Asp-Net-web-api/). If you need asynchronous upload, check out [this](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/uploading-files-asynchronously-using-asp.net-web-api.htm).

The "~/images/" in the MapPath can be a virtual folder.