# Angular won’t fade out an element on click...405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: jquery, angularjs

When I click the delete button on my twig file, it deletes but it doesn't fade away like it should be doing.

I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925823/angular-upload-405-method-not-allowed) but couldn't understand.

On the console I get the following error, it deletes though but doesn't fade away

```
angular.js:14525 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"message":"Method not allowed. Must be one of: GET"},"status":405,"config":{"method":"DELETE","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/todo/32","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Method Not Allowed"}
```

main.js

```
var app = angular.module('timmy',[]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location){

$scope.deleteTask = function(id){

    $http.delete('/todo/' + id).then(function(data, response, status, headers, config){
        $( 'task' + id ).fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

  }


// $scope.addTask = function(taskdata){


//  $http.post('/todo', taskdata).then(function(response){
//      // taskdata.task = '';
//      console.log("it works");
//  }, function(rejection){
//      console.log("it didn't work");
//  });


// }


});
```

todos.twig

```
{% extends "templates/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>My Todos</h1>

<ol>
  {% for task in tasks %}
        <div id="task{{task.id}}" class="myl" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <li><h4>{{ task.task}}</h4></li>
        <small style="font-style:italic">{{task.created_at |date("m/d/Y")}}</small></br>
        <small style="font-style:italic">{{ task.user.username}}</small>    
        </br>

    <button id="disappear" name="task" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="deleteTask({{task.id}})">Delete</button>



        </div>
    {% endfor %}

</ol>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve it, but you should check your API to get a 200 response.

```
 $http.delete('/todo/' + id).then(function(data){
    //This function is not being executed since you are getting a 405 response 
}, function(error){
    $( '#task' + id ).fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: @OwlMan While you mark this answer as accepted, which mean it works for you, why you trying to edit it and add `#`?